# Как использовать библиотеку Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics

Использую [клиентскую библиотеку для Google Analytics][1]
[1]: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client
Для авторизации использую такой код (ниже), но проблема в том что он работает только если я залогинен под тем акком для которого указаны данные.Можно как-то доработать код чтобы авторизация происходила только внутри кода и только когда он работает?, так чтобы можно было внутри скрипта прописать доступы от нужного аккаунта, ну т.е. я могу быть под другим акком в момент работы скрипта. Прошу прощения если объяснил плохо)

```
    // Загрузка клиентской библиотеки PHP для Google API.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);


// Если пользователь уже авторизовал это приложение, предоставьте токен доступа.
// В противном случае перенаправьте пользователя на страницу авторизации доступа в Google Analytics.
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  // Установка токена доступа на клиентском компьютере.
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

  // Создание авторизованного объекта службы аналитики.
  $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);

  // Вызов the Analytics Reporting API V4.
  $response = getReport($analytics);

  // Вывод ответа.
  printResults($response);

} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/apsga/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

Для более четкого понимания что я хочу...
Мне нужно чтобы он в этом месте

```
// Если пользователь уже авторизовал это приложение, предоставьте токен доступа. // В противном случае перенаправьте пользователя на страницу авторизации доступа в Google Analytics.
```

не перенаправлял пользователя на страницу авторизации доступа в Google Analytics, а логинел сам по тем доступам которые ему прописать. Если это вообще возможно)